# function 'free' on Haskell's FFI doesn't seem to work

Tags: haskell, ffi

I'm trying to get familiar with Haskell's FFI so I wrote this small example:

Main.hs:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.Ptr (Ptr)
import Foreign.Marshal.Array (peekArray)
import Foreign.Marshal.Alloc (free)

foreign import ccall "test.h test"
  test :: CInt -> Ptr CInt

main = do
  let rval = test 6

  -- print the array
  list <- peekArray 6 rval >>= return . map toInteger
  putStrLn $ show list

  free rval

  -- print it again (it should okay)
  putStrLn $ show list

  -- try to retrieve it AGAIN after I used free. Should print random values
  peekArray 6 rval >>= return . map toInteger >>= putStrLn . show
```

test.h

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

int* test(int a);

#endif
```

test.c

```
#include "test.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int* test(int a)
{
    int* r_val = (int*)malloc(a * sizeof(int));
    r_val[0] = 1;
    r_val[1] = 2;
    r_val[2] = 3;
    r_val[3] = 4;
    r_val[4] = 5;
    r_val[5] = 6;
    return r_val;
}
```

The output I get when I compile and run `Main.hs` is:

```
D:\Code\Haskell\Projects\Dev\TestFFI>cabal build
Building TestFFI-0.1.0.0...
Preprocessing executable 'TestFFI' for TestFFI-0.1.0.0...
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src\Main.hs, dist\build\TestFFI\TestFFI-tmp\Main.o )
Linking dist\build\TestFFI\TestFFI.exe ...

D:\Code\Haskell\Projects\Dev\TestFFI>
D:\Code\Haskell\Projects\Dev\TestFFI>dist\build\TestFFI\TestFFI.exe
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
[1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

That doesn't seem to make any sense to me. The 3rd time I printed the array I was expecting something like:

```
[69128391783,2083719073,934857983457,98374293874,0239823947,2390847289347]
```

random data!

Am I doing something wrong? Have I missed something?

Comment: Why do you think the freed memory should get changed? Note that the Haskell runtime doesn't use malloc/free to manage memory.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Reading memory after you've freed it is undefined behavior. Anything is allowed -- including returning random data, summoning nasal demons, or even, in the boringest of possible worlds, returning the data that was in that memory before it was freed.

Comment: Yeah but shouldn't there be a random chance for that undefined behavior? Every time I run the program I get the same output. If the behavior was undefined (as it should) wouldn't the output be different every time?

Comment: @TheCrafter No, there is no guarantee. Try to do the same in C. After `free` you might (consistently!) see the same data. Or not. Everything is possible. Undefined does not mean random, it means that the runtime can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @TheCrafter: There may be a random chance of the UB being visible--but it may be a very small chance, so you'd have to re-run the program many millions of times before you saw it. Or, you could demo it for an investor, which would pretty much guarantee the worst case immediately showing up (like the computer going up in smoke, instead of just printing out random garbage).

Comment: @TheCrafter Instead of answering your question directly, I pose a puzzle to you: by what mechanism are you imagining the computer getting entropy to use when deciding whether to output garbage or to output the last writes to memory? (Perhaps if we can understand *why* you think the computer can do truly random -- as opposed to arbitrary! -- things, we can cure you of this misconception.)

Comment: @DanielWagner "Freeing" an address means that this address is again available for allocation, it doesn't mean that something will write on it. My guess is that if I free an address and try to access it later I will find what there was there before unless something else is written there. Am I close enough?

Comment: @TheCrafter That pretty much matches my intuition of what will happen in most extant implementations, yup! With that expectation in mind: modern machines have gigabytes of memory, so expecting a particular six bytes to change in the course of a few cycles is pretty unreasonable, especially considering the way allocators typically reserve a "small chunks" pool of memory that is never returned to the OS -- hence smaller chunks are unlikely to be walked on by other processes -- and the way OS's typically reassign memory FIFO-style -- hence recently freed memory will take a while to be reassigned.

Comment: @DanielWagner Okay I got it. But hey wanna hear something weird I didn't mention on my post? What actually confused me in the first place was that when I wrote the program it actually printed random values on 1st, 3rd and 4th elements. Then, after a few hours it printed the correct values every time. I didn't mention it because I didn't want people to believe I'm on drugs while coding!

Comment: @TheCrafter Despite my intuitions, anything is allowed with use-after-free!

Comment: @DanielWagner Yeah like you said...undefined behavior! Thanks for your help :)